# Periodically close and reopen csv file to reduce memory load

Tags: python, csv, selenium

I am writing a script for a moderately large scrape to a .csv file using selenium. Approx 15,000 row, 10 columns per row. When I ran a 300ish row test, I noticed that towards the end, it seemed to be running a bit slower than when it started. That could have been just my perception, or could have been internet speed related I guess. But I had a thought that until I run `csv_file.close()`, the file isn't written to disk and I assume the data is all kept in a memory buffer or something?

So would it make sense to periodically close then reopen the csv file (every to help speed up the script by reducing the memory load? Or is there some larger problem that this will create? Or is the whole idea stupid because I was imagining the script slowing down? The 300ish row scrape produced a csv file around 39kb, which doesn't seem like much, but I just don't know if python keeping that kind of data in memory will slow it down or not.

Pastebin of full script with some obfuscation if it makes any difference : http://pastebin.com/T3VN1nHC
*Please note script is not completely finished. I am working on making it end-user friendly so there are a few loose ends around the runtime at this point still.

Comment: Why don't you use a database? Even SQLite would be a better idea than a CSV file.

Comment: The information will at most probably be used for generating mailing address labels. I've never used SQL before. Would there be any real benefit? csv seemed simple/easy which I assumed would translate into quicker runtime. Considering I'm having to selenium scrape the site, I'm looking down the barrel of a 18ish hour scrape.

Comment: Simple to *implement* doesn't necessarily mean *faster*. And what happens if you e.g. crash part way through scraping? It doesn't really matter what you're doing with the data next.

Comment: Fair point. I was concerned about that 'crash mid scrape' issue. I have never used SQLite or any other SQL flavour before. I'm doing some reading but do you have any resources that you recommend? How easy will it be to produce something that is end-user digestable such as an xls or csv?

Comment: It seems a bit premature to blame csv writing for vaguely perceived slowness. How have you estimated 18 hours to scrape? Perhaps you could patch out the csv-writing i.e. scrape the data but don't write the csv; how long does that take? What's your plan to do further performance testing? Note: 300 is a very small (1/50) sample of your 15K input and possibly not a very random sample.

Comment: 15000/300 = 50 btw.

Comment: @Lobsta well spotted ... fixed

Comment: And I just extrapolated out the runtime from the 300 scrape (22 minutes)  to get to 18 hours. I think I'm going to investigate the SQL approach. Sounds more integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Java and C# regularly and have no performance issues writing big CSV files. Writing to CSV or SQL or whatever is negligible vs actually scraping/navigating pages/sites. I would suggest that you do some extra logging so that you can see the time between scraped pages and time to write the CSV and rerun your 300 scrape test.

If you really want to go faster, split the input file into two parts and trigger the script twice. Now you are running at twice the speed... so ~9 hrs. That's going to be your biggest boost. You can trigger it a few more times and run 4+ on the same machine easily. I've done it a number of times (grid not needed).

The only other thing I can think of is to look at your scraping methods for inefficiencies but running at least two concurrent scripts is going to blow away all other improvements/efficiencies combined.

Comment: Not sure if you are overly familiar with selenium, but will that cause problems with the chromedriver.exe file being used for 2 concurrent scripts?

Comment: Nope. I was talking about using Selenium. I use it like this all the time. You just have to split your input file for each script or set up some logic and use SQL, etc.

Comment: Excellent, thankyou so much for that suggestion, I honestly wouldn't have thought of that. Forest for the trees kinda situation. The search form that I am scraping doesn't have a 'Jump to...page' link, only next/previous, so I'm gonna have to write in a `while current_page<start_page: click_next` fast forward style function, but your suggestion is going to save me so much time.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. For the issue with the page not having a jump to page link... take a look at the URL after you click a page link. There may be a page number in there that you can use to skip pages, etc.

Comment: Nah, I did already think of that. It's an .aspx form. URL Never changes.